# PayPal IPN Notifications Failing but not set

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the .net API and am successfully receiving payments. However, the last 2 mornings I have gotten an email saying:

> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the
>   following URL(s) are failing:
>
> http://localhost/NotifyMe
>
> If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
>   that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
>   with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
>   disabled for your account.
>
> Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

```
    PaymentDetailsType paymentDetail = new PaymentDetailsType();
                paymentDetail.PaymentAction = (PaymentActionCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("Sale", typeof(PaymentActionCodeType));
                //paymentDetail.NotifyURL = "http://localhost/NotifyMe";
paymentDetail.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue(Currency, typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), entry.Fee.ToString());
                List<PaymentDetailsType> paymentDetails = new List<PaymentDetailsType>();
```

In that code I used to have the notify url set, but i took it out. Are the emails just cached from a few days ago? To my knowledge I don't need the IPN as I'm only doing Express Checkout calls.

Comment: are u getting IPN for recurring payment transaction ?

Comment: No this is just one-off express transactions.

Comment: can you provide the transaction id?

Answer (score 1):

> Are the emails just cached from a few days ago?

The emails will continue while the IPN calls are still failing, and will continue to do so until the service hits the max retry count (it's currently set to retry 16 times a day for up to 4 days).

To disable IPN on your account, you can do the following:

1. Login to your PayPal account
2. Click your profile icon and click **Profile and Settings**
3. Click **My selling tools** on the left-hand side of the page
4. In the *Getting paid and managing my risk* section in the middle of the page, click the **Update** (or **Edit**) link in the row titled *Instant payment notifications*
5. Follow the instructions, and ensure you have **Do not receive IPN messages (Disabled)** selected
6. Click **Save** to save your settings

This will ensure IPN is disabled for your account.  However, you may still receive the emails until the IPN service reaches the max retry count.

Comment: Strangely when I go to this setting in my account it is set to "Disabled" already.  What happens when it reaches the retry count? Does it just give up or will it disable my api credentials?

Comment: @Adrian, it should just give up once the retry count is hit.  The note about disabling of IPN on the account is for cases where the service is being abused.  Your case is pretty typical where it's clearly a test URL that accidentally made its way into your live calls.  If you do ever run into trouble with IPN being disabled, you can always contact [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) for help in getting things cleared up.